# How to design a database to create associations between multiple modules?

Tags: database-design

Lets say our web application consist of many modules. Each module has its own table.

Now if i need to keep relationship between my module and another module, ideally i will create another table like module1_module2_relationship which will have module 1 pk and module 2 pk. Assuming I also need to store some more columns regarding this relationship I will add some more columns to this relationship table.

But my module can have relationship to many modules and I dont want to create new table for every module.

The main point here is given my module Id, I need to know what all modules it is associated with? And I don't want to run a query against each relationship table just find out if module id exist in table.

How do I design such database?

Answer (score 0):

> our web application consist of many modules. Each module has its own table.

OK.  That's interesting...

> if i need to keep relationship between my module and another module, ideally i will create another table

Yup.  Exactly right.

> But my module can have relationship to many modules

Not a problem!

> I dont want to create new table for every module.

Whoa!!!!

You'll have exactly *one* "module relations" table.  Each row will have *two* foreign keys: one for each "module".

Add a new relationship?  Simple: add a new row.

Create a new relationship to a new module?  Equally simple: just add another row.

One relationship table.  As many/as few rows as you need.  It's really as easy as that :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I have only one relationship table with just pk columns how do I know module name by just looking at pk. Also in all probability it might also happen that I might need to store not only pk for a module but few more columns from that module. e.g. Module 1 PK  - Module 2 PK, Module 2 (some other column. And the number of columns may vary for each module.

Comment: You can go in some direction like you can add few more columns in your relationship table, like module1name, module1ID,module2Name, module2ID.here i think could solve your issue or no?

Answer (score 0):

You could make one table to hold all the relationships with columns describing the modules as well as the PKs of the module:

```
tblModuleRelationship
---------------------
Module1_Name
Module1_PK
Module2_Name
Module2_PK
```

and create a unique constraint across all 4 columns.

The obvious downside to this is that you can't really use a FK relationship